Ticks of matshow subfigures from sliced array
My numpy array has shape of (500,6). Since it's very tall, I'm plotting slices of it with matplotlib matshow.
This is my code:
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5) = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(6,12), layout='constrained', sharex=True)

min = q_func.min()
max = q_func.max()

plt.rcParams.update({"text.usetex": True,"font.family": "Computer Modern Serif"})
ax1.matshow(q_func[0:99,:], vmin=min, vmax=max, aspect='equal', cmap='viridis')
ax2.matshow(q_func[100:199,:], vmin=min, vmax=max, aspect='equal', cmap='viridis')
ax3.matshow(q_func[200:299,:], vmin=min, vmax=max, aspect='equal', cmap='viridis')
ax4.matshow(q_func[300:399,:], vmin=min, vmax=max, aspect='equal', cmap='viridis')
im = ax5.matshow(q_func[400:499,:], vmin=min, vmax=max, aspect='equal', cmap='viridis')

fig.supxlabel("Acciones")
fig.supylabel("Estados")
fig.suptitle("$Q$-función aproximada con 2000 episodios")
fig.colorbar(im)

Which outputs:

But I want the second subfigure y-ticks match those of the sliced array, so they start from the origin as 100, 120, ...
The same for the other subfigures: 200, 220, ...; 300, 320,...; 400, 420, ...
So it should look like this:

But I haven't had luck so far. If someone knows how to achieve this, I'll be grateful.
I have tried ax.set_yticks, ax.set_yticklabels. But I haven't had luck so far. If someone knows how to achieve this, I'll be grateful.

Edit:
I tried adding
ax2.set_yticks(ax2.get_yticks())
ax2.set_yticklabels(["","",100,120,140,160,180])

which makes this
and
ax2.set_yticks([i for i in range(100,200)])

gives this

What did you try with ax.set_yticks? That should work.

I added it to the post

What if you did ax2.set_yticks(range(0, 100, 20), labels=range(100, 200, 20))?

Got it, that gives my desired output. Thanks for the help.

You can select the current ticks and label it with the ticks + 100.
ax2.set_yticks(range(0, 100, 20), labels=range(100, 200, 20))

You can avoid code duplication by writing it in a loop.
for i, ax in enumerate([ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4]):
    ax.set_yticks(range(0, 100, 20), labels=range(i*100, i*100+100, 20))


This works but is pretty suboptimal.  Just use the “extents” kwarg
